# postgresql- slow update query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm working with a table that has about 19 million rows and 60 columns (bigtable). Of the 19 million records, about 17 million have x and y coordinates (about 1.8 million distinct combinations of x and y). I needed to add some additional geocoded information to the table from another file (census_geocode). I've created a lookup table (distinct_xy) that has a list of all the distinct x and y coordinate pairs and an ID. I have indexes on bigtable (x_coord, y_coord), census_geocode (x_coord, y_coord), and distinct_xy (x_coord, y_coord), and a primary key in distinct_xy (xy_id) and census_geocode (xy_id). So here's the query:

```
Update bigtable
set block_grp = cg.blkgrp,
block = cg.block,
tract = cg.tractce10
from census_geocode cg, distinct_xy xy
where bigtable.x_coord = xy.x_coord and
bigtable.y_coord=xy.y_coord and cg.xy_id=xy.xy_id;
```

This is running *extremely* slowly. as in:

```
"Update on bigtable     (cost=17675751.51..17827040.74 rows=22 width=327)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=17675751.51..17827040.74 rows=22 width=327)"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=17675751.51..17826856.26 rows=22 width=312)"
"              Merge Cond: ((bigtable.x_coord = xy.x_coord) AND (bigtable.y_coord = xy.y_coord))"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=17318145.58..17366400.81 rows=19302092 width=302)"
"                    Sort Key: bigtable.x_coord, bigtable.y_coord"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on bigtable  (cost=0.00..1457709.92 rows=19302092 width=302)"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=357588.42..366887.02 rows=1859720 width=26)"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=357588.42..362237.72 rows=1859720 width=26)"
"                          Sort Key: xy.x_coord, xy.y_coord"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on distinct_xy xy  (cost=0.00..30443.20 rows=1859720 width=26)"
"        ->  Index Scan using census_geocode_pkey on census_geocode cg  (cost=0.00..8.37 rows=1 width=23)"
"              Index Cond: (xy_id = xy.xy_id)"
```

I've also tried splitting this apart and inserting the lookup key back into the big table to avoid the multi-table join.

```
Update bigtable
set xy_id = xy.xy_id
from distinct_xy xy
where bigtable.x_coord = xy.x_coord and bigtable.y_coord=xy.y_coord;
```

this also runs for hours without completing.

```
"Update on bigtable  (cost=0.00..20577101.71 rows=22 width=404)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..20577101.71 rows=22 width=404)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on distinct_xy xy  (cost=0.00..30443.20 rows=1859720 width=26)"
"        ->  Index Scan using rae_xy_idx on bigtable  (cost=0.00..11.03 rows=1 width=394)"
"              Index Cond: ((x_coord = xy.x_coord) AND (y_coord = xy.y_coord))"
```

Can someone please help me improve this query's performance?

Comment: Maybe add output of `\d bigtable`?

Comment: can you add the output from `explain analyze`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get an output from explain analyze, because I've never managed to complete the query (I usually give up when I let it go overnight, and come back the next day to find that it still hasn't finished...)

Comment: Did you check for a record lock? pg_stat_activity can show you if your query is waiting for another query to finish.

Comment: no record lock. I'm the only one working in the database, so this is the only query running.

Comment: Try to create a temporary table which holds `xy.x_coord`, `xy.y_coord`, `cg.blkgrp`, `cg.block`, and `cg.tractce10`, then run an update with only `bigtable` and the temporary table in the query. That should leave `bigtable` out of the picture until its time for `UPDATE`